# Vue-slider-component does not provide default export

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use [Vue Slider Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slider-component?activeTab=readme). I have the following simple component as part of my app:

```
<template>
<div>
    <vue-slider></vue-slider>
</div>
</template>

<script>
// App.vue
import VueSlider from 'vue-slider-component'
import 'vue-slider-component/theme/default.css'

export default {
    components: {
        VueSlider
    }
}
</script>
```

I am using vue 3.3.4 with vite 4.5.2, but whenever I try using this component I get the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/vue-slider-component/dist/vue-slider-component.umd.min.js?v=6ac5c133' does not provide an export named 'default'`

As far as I can tell, the component does not provide any named imports either, so what am I overlooking?

Comment: What is the version number of the installed component?  The documentation has two different install commands.  Did you install the Vue 3 compatible version?

Comment: I am using version 4.1.0-beta.7

Comment: My own local test works just fine.  It might only be possible to solve if you provide a fully runnable example, like a github repo.  Or you could try creating a new issue on the component github page and see if the author or other users of the library can help.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll try making a minimal example and work up from there to see if I can nail down the issue.

Answer (score -1):

As the docs, you must install it as @next version to use it with Vue 3.
If you using npm:

```
npm uninstall vue-slider-component
npm install vue-slider-component@next --save
```

If you using yarn:

```
yarn remove vue-slider-component
yarn add vue-slider-component@next
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: I already install the package using the recommended command, and as such I have version 4.1.0-beta.7 installed, but I am still facing the same issue